# VPN IKE Renegotiation causing dropped database connections in Glassfish

Tags: amazon-ec2, glassfish, vpn, amazon-vpc, checkpoint

We have a Checkpoint VPN connection to the AWS cloud.  Our database connections appear to be dropping during the IKE renegotiation that happens regularly during a 24 hour period.  In general the renegotiation takes less than 60 seconds, but our database connections are dropping in Glassfish 4.1.1, our application server. A failed connection validation always precedes the dropped connection.   What can be done to keep these connections alive longer (no timeouts) so that they don't drop when the renegotiation is being done ?

Comment: I would suggest approaching this from a different perspective:  Rekeying should be possible without any loss of connectivity.

Comment: Hi, are you referring to a two-tunnel setup?

Comment: No.  I've used single-tunnel setups into VPC VPN with other equipment (Cisco ASA, Meraki MX) and never encountered a loss of connectivity during rekeying.

Comment: I guess it's basically a matter of keeping the connection open and not timing out. Would that configuration be done in the client (Glassfish) or the server (MSSQL) ? Anyone?